# How to color the text logs file based on Error type in NLog

Tags: logging, nlog, error-logging, serilog

I am using Nlog library in my application to logs the files.It is logging the files in text format, but i need to color the text based on error type.

logger.Info("Info error has occured"); - blue color.
logger.Error("An error has occured" +ex.message); - Red color.

But it is working fine in console application,how to set the same in text file?

```
 <target name="coloredConsole" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="false"
    +        layout="${longdate}|${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|${message}" >
```

Comment: Have you ever seen colored text file? The first question is what software you are using to view text files. And then check what formatting it requires to add color to the displayed text. Next, search for appropriate NLog target or write your own.